# Creating a regular graph or adjacency matrix in R, with igraph?

Tags: r, matrix, igraph

I am currently trying to (ideally) use igraph to generate a regular adjacency matrix. I would like each unit to be neighbors with k people.

For k = 2, I am hoping to get:

```
library(igraph)
as_adj(make_graph(c(1, 2, 1, 10, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5 ,5,6, 6,7, 7,8, 8,9, 9, 10), directed = FALSE))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
 [2,]    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [3,]    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
 [4,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
 [5,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    0     0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1     0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
[10,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
```

Is there a way to use existing functions in `igraph` to create graphs such as the one above, but for a generic k? Thanks.

Comment: You say that you want a "cycle graph" but it does not seem clear what that means for k>2. Do you just want a graph such that all nodes have degree =k?

Comment: @G5W Yes, that is the idea, thanks!

Comment: That is called a "regular graph", not a "cycle graph". Can you please update the title to reflect what you are actually looking for? From your other comments, it seems like you actually want a "connected regular graph".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [`sample_degseq`](http://igraph.org/r/doc/sample_degseq.html):

"It is often useful to create a graph with given vertex degrees. This is exactly what sample_degseq
does."

```
k=3 # degree for each node
n=10 # number of nodes
g = sample_degseq(rep(k,n),method = "simple.no.multiple")
```

Adjacency:

```
as_adj(g)

[1,] . . 1 . 1
[2,] . . 1 1 .
[3,] 1 1 . . .
[4,] . 1 . . 1
[5,] 1 . . 1 .
```

Plot:

```
plot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: It seems that sometimes the above function randomly generates two networks which are not connected together. Is there a way to force a connection between each node? In other words, sometimes when I run the code, nodes 8,6,4 are in a network, which the rest are in a network. Thanks!

Comment: You could put it in a while loop, and use `edge_connectivity(g)` to check if the graph contains networks that are not connected. In that case it will return 0. Hope that helps!